# By what can an anaphor be realized?

Tags: discourse, references, anaphora

According to the definition I read on anaphors, it is an expression, which refers back to a word. As examples  what this anaphoras can be I was given a pronoun and adverb:

Anaphor realized by a pronoun:

> Teresa caressed the dying tree, **her** well formed lips were about to kiss it good-bye

Anaphor realized by an adverb:

> Chris avoided to hug her, in doing **so** he made sure there will be nothing left of him once the memories were gone.

How about other realizations? Are there any? Could a whole sentence be an anaphor, if not, why not?

Comment: A little technical correction: *anaphora* is the fact or state of referring, and the term which refers is an *anaphor*. Relatives,  demonstratives, reflexives, reciprocals, and some fused-head determinatives are also anaphors. Sentences may be the referents (antecedents) of anaphors.

Comment: Lakoff's anaphoric hierarchy listed, in decreasing order, the following anaphor types: proper names, definite descriptions, epithets, and pronouns. Any anaphor of one type may refer to an antecedent of a higher type. So pronouns can refer to anything, epithets (_the bastard_) to definite descriptions or proper names, and d. desc to p. names only. At the bottom, after pronouns, is `Zero`, of course, which is the most common anaphor in many languages.

Comment: So an anaphors could form a chain, anaphor1 refers back to an expression, this expression is anaphor2 to another expression and so forth as long each anaphor points to an expression within a higher rank?

Comment: Higher or same. Pronouns can be repeated indefinitely, for instance, and usually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are [2 ways of defining anaphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)); the narrower definition you're using refers back to an antecedent; the broader definition includes cataphors, which refer forward to a later word or phrase, and exophors, which refer to something outside of the text (e.g. when you point and say "There it is!", "it" is an exophor).

Anaphors can include:

- Pronouns (he, she, her, it, this, etc., as in your example)
- Adverbs (like "so", as in your example)
- Nouns (like "thing", "place", etc., or any kind of [hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy)):

  > The rat crawled up Martha's leg.  She cried out when she saw the **creature**.
- Verbs (like "do"):

  > "I can play this song pretty well, but Sam **does** it better."
- Phrases:

  > [After long explanation of a method] "**This way of doing things** is unnecessarily complicated.  Let's look at an easier method."

Comment: So, the phrase level is the limit, there is no way a clause could serve as an anaphor?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't.  Just have to think of an example.